# Problem with populating database column with seeding in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding

I need to populate my database column from seeding. I have 'interested_in' column in user_profiles table and I need to populate it with according id from 'value_id' column from user_interests table. Both user_profiles and user_interests table are connected to users table ('user_id' column is in both tables). So if the value of 'value_id' column is for example 1 it needs to be 1 in 'interested_in' column, I need help on how to populate that 'interested_in' column from seeders. 'value_id' column is already populated. Here are my tables and example data and my code so far but it doesn't work currently, it shows 'Array to string conversion' error.

user_interests table

```
user_id    field_id    value_id
   1           1           1
```

user_profiles table

```
id    user_id    interested_in
 1       1           and here needs to be 1, to associate value_id (1) from user_interests table
```

UserProfileTableSeeder.php

```
class UserProfileTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    use ChunkSeeder;

    public function run()
    {
        $users = User::all()->pluck('id');

        $user_interests = DB::table('user_interests')->select('value_id')->where('field_id', 1)->get();
        $user_interests_values = $user_interests->pluck('value_id')->toArray(); 

        $seed = [];

        foreach ($users as $userId) {
            $seed[] = factory(UserProfile::class)->make(
                [
                    'user_id' => $userId,
                    'interested_in' =>  $user_interests_values, // Shows array to string error!!!
                ]
            )->toArray();
        }

        $this->seedChunks($seed, [UserProfile::class, 'insert']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's why `$user_interests_values` is an array as you can see in this line (at the end):

```php
$user_interests_values = $user_interests->pluck('value_id')->toArray();
```

Try in the factory to change `$user_interests_values` to `current($user_interests_values)` or probably `$user_interests_values['id']` or whatever.

PS: I am not really sure what's inside `$user_interests_values`, you can see it with a `dd()` and running the migration then (don't worry, the migration won't be successful because of the `dd()` and you will be able to run it later again until it finishes properly.

By the way, I recommend you to do something more legible than you did in your `rum()` method. I mean, something like this:

```php
$interest = factory(UserInterests::class)->create();

factory(UserProfiles::class, 20)->create([
    'interest' => $interest->id,
]);
```